# stack corruption detected Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

My `Android` App crashes on specific device but works fine on every other device i've tested. i try to do AES Encryption in NDK

**Device Name**: Telenor Infinity (Local Vendor)

**Android OS ver**.: 6.0

Here is the Error Log from the faulty device:

```
04-15 23:11:42.815 6965-6965/? A/AEE/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    Build fingerprint: 'TELENOR/TELENOR_Infinity_i/TELENOR_Infinity_i:6.0/MRA58K/1471877097:user/release-keys'
    Revision: '0'
    ABI: 'arm'
04-15 23:11:42.816 6965-6965/? A/AEE/DEBUG: pid: 6896, tid: 6896, name: ker.sed.dms.app  >>> com.tracker.sed.dms.app <<<
    signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
04-15 23:11:42.845 6965-6965/? A/AEE/DEBUG: Abort message: 'stack corruption detected'
        r0 00000000  r1 00001af0  r2 00000006  r3 b6feee2c
        r4 b6feee34  r5 b6feede4  r6 00000002  r7 0000010c
        r8 b4338f7d  r9 b4736a00  sl beae9c90  fp b4736a00
        ip 00000006  sp beae98e8  lr b6d57d4d  pc b6d59408  cpsr 400b0010
04-15 23:11:42.861 6965-6965/? A/AEE/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 00042408  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
        #01 pc 00040d49  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+32)
        #02 pc 0001c7eb  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
        #03 pc 0001999d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
        #04 pc 00017550  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
04-15 23:11:42.862 6965-6965/? A/AEE/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0001b3ff  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_fatal+16)
        #06 pc 000418bb  /system/lib/libc.so (__stack_chk_fail+6)
        #07 pc 00003acf  /data/app/com.tracker.sed.dms.app-2/base.apk (offset 0x81c000)
        #08 pc 00153130  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3Dbg13TagFromObjectERKNS_27ScopedObjectAccessUncheckedEPNS_6mirror6ObjectE.part.312+399)
        #09 pc 0002ab4c  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (deleted)
```

**aes_util.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include "aes.h"
#include "sha1.h"
#include "string.h"

//CRYPT CONFIG
#define MAX_LEN (2*1024*1024)
#define ENCRYPT 0
#define DECRYPT 1
#define AES_KEY_SIZE 128
#define READ_LEN 10

#define TARGET_CLASS "com/tracker/sed/dms/app/helpers/AES"
#define TARGET_CRYPT "crypt"
#define TARGET_CRYPT_SIG "([BLjava/lang/String;I)[B"
#define TARGET_CRYPT_SIMPLE "cryptSimple"
#define TARGET_CRYPT_SIMPLE_SIG "([BLjava/lang/String;I)[B"
#define TARGET_READ "read"
#define TARGET_READ_SIG "(Ljava/lang/String;J)[B"



/*
 * Class:     tv_fun_common_crypt_Funcrypt
 * Method:    sha1
 * Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;JI)[Ljava/lang/Object;
 */
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL android_native_aes(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
                                                jbyteArray jarray, jstring partialKey, jint jmode) {

    unsigned char* pKey = (unsigned char*)(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, partialKey, 0);
    unsigned int pKeylen = (unsigned int) ((*env)->GetStringLength(env, partialKey));

    unsigned char copydatahere[128] = {0};

    memcpy(copydatahere,AES_KEY1, sizeof(AES_KEY1));
    memcpy(copydatahere + sizeof(AES_KEY1) ,pKey,pKeylen);

    SHA1_CTX sha;
    uint8_t results[20];
    char *buf;
    int n;
    //char *shakey = {0};

    char output[(sizeof(results) * 2) + 1];
    char *ptr = &output[0];


    buf = (char *) copydatahere;
    n = strlen(buf);
    SHA1Init(&sha);
    SHA1Update(&sha, (uint8_t *)buf, n);
    SHA1Final(results, &sha);
    for (n = 0; n < 20; n++) {
        ptr += sprintf(ptr, "%02x", results[n]);
    }

    unsigned char AES_KEY11[16] = {0};
    memcpy(AES_KEY11,output,16);

    //check input data
    unsigned int len = (unsigned int) ((*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jarray));
    if (len <= 0 || len >= MAX_LEN) {
        return NULL;
    }

    unsigned char *data = (unsigned char*) (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env,
                                                                        jarray, NULL);
    if (!data) {
        return NULL;
    }

    unsigned int mode = (unsigned int) jmode;
    unsigned int rest_len = len % AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    unsigned int padding_len = (
            (ENCRYPT == mode) ? (AES_BLOCK_SIZE - rest_len) : 0);
    unsigned int src_len = len + padding_len;

    unsigned char *input = (unsigned char *) malloc(src_len);
    memset(input, 0, src_len);
    memcpy(input, data, len);
    if (padding_len > 0) {
        memset(input + len, (unsigned char) padding_len, padding_len);
    }

    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, jarray, data, 0);

    unsigned char * buff = (unsigned char*) malloc(src_len);
    if (!buff) {
        free(input);
        return NULL;
    }
    memset(buff, src_len, 0);

    //set key & iv
    unsigned int key_schedule[AES_BLOCK_SIZE * 4] = { 0 };
    aes_key_setup(AES_KEY11, key_schedule, AES_KEY_SIZE);
    //aes_key_setup(copydatahere, key_schedule, AES_KEY_SIZE);

    if (mode == ENCRYPT) {
        aes_encrypt_cbc(input, src_len, buff, key_schedule, AES_KEY_SIZE,
                        AES_KEY11);//AES_IV
    } else {
        aes_decrypt_cbc(input, src_len, buff, key_schedule, AES_KEY_SIZE,
                        AES_KEY11);//AES_IV
    }

    if (ENCRYPT != mode) {
        unsigned char * ptr = buff;
        ptr += (src_len - 1);
        padding_len = (unsigned int) *ptr;
        if (padding_len > 0 && padding_len <= AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
            src_len -= padding_len;
        }
        ptr = NULL;
    }

    jbyteArray bytes = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, src_len);
    (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, bytes, 0, src_len, (jbyte*) buff);

    free(input);
    free(buff);

    return bytes;
}

JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL android_native_aes_simple(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
                                                jbyteArray jarray, jstring finalKey, jint jmode) {

    unsigned char* fKey = (unsigned char*)(*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, finalKey, 0);

    unsigned char copydatahere[16] = {0};

    memcpy(copydatahere ,fKey,16);

    //check input data
    unsigned int len = (unsigned int) ((*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jarray));
    if (len <= 0 || len >= MAX_LEN) {
        return NULL;
    }

    unsigned char *data = (unsigned char*) (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env,
                                                                        jarray, NULL);
    if (!data) {
        return NULL;
    }

    unsigned int mode = (unsigned int) jmode;
    unsigned int rest_len = len % AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    unsigned int padding_len = (
            (ENCRYPT == mode) ? (AES_BLOCK_SIZE - rest_len) : 0);
    unsigned int src_len = len + padding_len;

    unsigned char *input = (unsigned char *) malloc(src_len);
    memset(input, 0, src_len);
    memcpy(input, data, len);
    if (padding_len > 0) {
        memset(input + len, (unsigned char) padding_len, padding_len);
    }

    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, jarray, data, 0);

    unsigned char * buff = (unsigned char*) malloc(src_len);
    if (!buff) {
        free(input);
        return NULL;
    }
    memset(buff, src_len, 0);

    //set key & iv
    unsigned int key_schedule[AES_BLOCK_SIZE * 4] = { 0 };
    aes_key_setup(copydatahere, key_schedule, AES_KEY_SIZE);
    //aes_key_setup(copydatahere, key_schedule, AES_KEY_SIZE);

    if (mode == ENCRYPT) {
        aes_encrypt_cbc(input, src_len, buff, key_schedule, AES_KEY_SIZE,
                        copydatahere);//AES_IV
    } else {
        aes_decrypt_cbc(input, src_len, buff, key_schedule, AES_KEY_SIZE,
                        copydatahere);//AES_IV
    }

    if (ENCRYPT != mode) {
        unsigned char * ptr = buff;
        ptr += (src_len - 1);
        padding_len = (unsigned int) *ptr;
        if (padding_len > 0 && padding_len <= AES_BLOCK_SIZE) {
            src_len -= padding_len;
        }
        ptr = NULL;
    }

    jbyteArray bytes = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, src_len);
    (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, bytes, 0, src_len, (jbyte*) buff);

    free(input);
    free(buff);

    return bytes;
}

JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL android_native_read(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
                                                 jstring jstr, jlong jtimestam) {
    char * path = (char *) (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jstr, NULL);
    if (!path) {
        return NULL;
    }
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        return NULL;
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jstr, path);

    char pBuf[READ_LEN + 1] = { 0 };
    fread(pBuf, 1, READ_LEN, fp);
    pBuf[READ_LEN] = 0;
    fclose(fp);

    jbyteArray bytes = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, READ_LEN);
    (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, bytes, 0, READ_LEN, (jbyte*) pBuf);

    return bytes;
}

static const JNINativeMethod gMethods[] = { { TARGET_CRYPT, TARGET_CRYPT_SIG,
                                                    (void*) android_native_aes },
                                            { TARGET_CRYPT_SIMPLE, TARGET_CRYPT_SIMPLE_SIG,
                                                    (void*) android_native_aes_simple },
                                            { TARGET_READ, TARGET_READ_SIG,
                                                    (void*) android_native_read } };

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    JNIEnv* env = NULL;
    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
        return -1;
    }

    jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, TARGET_CLASS);
    if (!clazz) {
        return -1;
    }

    if ((*env)->RegisterNatives(env, clazz, gMethods,
                                sizeof(gMethods) / sizeof(gMethods[0])) != JNI_OK) {
        return -1;
    }
    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL JNI_OnUnload(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    JNIEnv* env = NULL;
    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void**) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
        return;
    }
}
```

There was a stack corruption detected. I am unable to understand why it works on every other device and fails on that specific one. 
help me in Tracing the problem.

**Answer**

By increasing the size of copydatahere[128] problem was solved :)

Thanks **Michael Walz** for identifying the problem

Comment: Possibly a buffer overflow of `copydatahere`. Try `char copydatahere[256];` or so and see if the bug goes away. There are other local array, try also to make them bigger and see what happens. Remember: "undefined bahaviour" includes "apparently working fine".

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thanks man
its resolved

Comment: What was the problem? You can answer your own question.